# Will mktime string reflect time offset as a date() variable?

Tags: php, date, time, timezone, mktime

I'm using the following code...

```
$TOffset = 3;
$TIME = mktime(date("H")+$TOffset,date("i"),date("s"),date("m"), date("d"),date("Y"));
$DateTime = date("YmdHis",$TIME);
$Date = date("Ymd",$TIME);
```

Let's say the current date and time is 2013-05-08 @ 1am your time(EST). The server is 3 hours behind you (PST) will `$Date` based on the code above reflect 20130508010000 or 20130507220000?

I love PHP, but when dealing with time in PHP there are so many variables and things to consider it's mind boggling.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: No I didn't, I guess I could consider the servers current datetime and set the offset variable enough to reflect tomorrow. I didn't even think of that. Thank you.

Comment: Just tested, it WILL reflect the offset. It's been a long day and I am not a PHP guru. I wish I would have thought of that before asking. Thanks again!